# count total number of comma separated countries in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of countries I would like to get a count of in a data frame column.

```
 ship_to_countries

 Albania, Algeria, Azerbaijan, Bahrain, France, Georgia
 Ireland, England, France, Germany
 France, Germany,
 Ireland
```

How can I create a column to the right which has the count of countries in pandas?

I've tried this solution but I get a count of how many times a single country is listed.
so If `Isreal` is in my column once 16 times I get 16. I'd like only get only how many countries are in each pandas row.

```
(df['ship_to_countries'].str.count(',')
                      .add(1)
                      .groupby(df.ship_to_countries)
                      .sum())
```

Comment: I don't get what is wrong with just `df['ship_to_countries'].str.count(',').add(1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split()` and `len`:

```
df["count"] = df["ship_to_countries"].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(",")))
```